How to Mock a WebMethod in Mockito
I am working on a Java project where I need to write unit tests with testng for a class that has a method similar to the following:
public boolean isValidCode(String code) {
    // Some logic here
    return service.exists(new CodeInput(code));
}

The isValidCode method calls a method exists from a service interface GenericService. The exists method in GenericService is responsible for checking the existence of a code. The issue I'm facing is that the exists method is WebMethod which I don't actually want invoked.
Here's the interface for GenericService:
@WebService(name = "GenericService", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/GenericService")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface GenericService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GenericExists", action = "http://example.com/GenericService/GenericExists")
    @WebResult(name = "GenericExistsResponse", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/GenericService", partName = "response")
    public GenericExists exists(
        @WebParam(name = "GenericExistsRequest", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/GenericService", partName = "CodeInput")
        CodeInput codeInput);
}

Is there any way I can mock the exists method in my GenericService class to simply return true when invoked? I just want to test the "isValidCodeMethod" for my tests.
I tried using Mockito to do the following:
CodeInput codeInput = mock(CodeInput.class);
GenericService serviceMock = mock(GenericService.class);
when(genericService.exists(any(CodeInput.class))).thenReturn(true);

But I get a null pointer exception when I do this.

Are you talking about a reserved socket/port for tcp-transactions?

@Grim No, the issue is not related to a reserved socket/port. I'm trying to figure out if I can use the WireMock library to mock HTTP endpoints for testing purposes. In my development environment, the actual web service endpoint isn't available, so I'm considering setting up a mock server to simulate the responses from the web service.

When you do unit testing, you don't need any endpoints. You mock anything outside the tested method(s). So the code you showed looks correct to me for a unit test. To help you with the NPE, we would need to see that stacktrace and more of the test code.

Ensure your YourClass has the isValidCode method and inject the GenericService properly.
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public class YourClassTest {

    @Mock
    private GenericService genericService;

    @InjectMocks
    private YourClass yourClass;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidCode() {
        // Arrange
        CodeInput codeInput = new CodeInput("testCode");
        when(genericService.exists(any(CodeInput.class))).thenReturn(new GenericExists(true));

        // Act
        boolean result = yourClass.isValidCode("testCode");

        // Assert
        assertTrue(result);
    }
}


@InjectMocks: Injects the mock GenericService into your class.
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this): Initializes the mock objects.


Thank you so much for that! I forgot about using Inject Mocks to make sure the mocks were injected into the object I was testing. I really appreciate it.

Try using mountebank
https://www.mbtest.org/
very easy to learn, use and deploy. provide various features like conditional proxy. you can have partial conditional mocks and rest all can be transferred to actual service/target as well.
